# systemjs.config.js doesn't work in Visual Studio 2017? (ag-grid)

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2017, ag-grid

I'm trying to install ag-grid into my ASP.net MVC project right now in VS2017.

Everything seems to be just like in the example : https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-systemjs/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0

Except the compiler tells me things like /ag-grid/main can't be found (in a few of my TS files that are related to the grid). Googling told me it has to do with the systemjs.config.js

The problem seems to be with the systemjs.config.js . Tells me something about invalid text tokens and it being an invalid xml-document? 
It's marked red in the project-explorer as well. Says "checked in".

I am absolutely clueless what is happening here right now, please help.

(sorry if the error codes are a little vague, I had to translate them)

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty broad question, because it depends if you are using ASP DotNet Framework or ASP DotNet Core.  It also depends if you are doing a true SPA (single page application) or if you're mixing in some RAZR pages as well.

I'm working on series of tutorials for ASP.NET, Angular, and ag-grid.  I have a solution that I got working for Visual Studio 2017 ASP DotNet Core base website, REST controllers for providing data, a single index.html as a SPA for Angular 4 on Windows 7.  These are the steps that worked for me.  This is along answer, but that's because there's a lot of steps to get ASP DotNet Core, MVC, Angular 4, and ag-grid all cooperating together.

**Summary**

- Make an empty ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET core)
- Fix Startup.cs to only serve wwwroot/index.html
- Download the simple ag-grid angular sample into web folder, tell it
  to copy transpiled output to wwwroot folder
- Run Visual Studio, it will open a browser from C# code that serves an
  Angular 4 SPA page that shows ag-grid in action

**Detailed Steps**

1. This example assumes I will make a solution c:\code\Elephant\ElephantSolution with a subdirectory ...\ElephantSolution\ElephantWeb with a web project.  The name "Elephant" is just random, and the actual directory locations aren't important, but I keep it consistent so these steps make more sense.
2. Visual Studio 2017, project File/New/Project
3. Pick Templates/Visual C#/.Net Core/ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)

   - Name: ElephantWeb
   - Location: c:\code\Elephant
   - Solution name: ElephantSolution
   - ASP.NET Core 1.1 Templates: Empty
4. I can run this in Visual Studio and get "Hello World!" as expected.
5. Next I have to plug in Angular 4.  To prepare, tell Visual Studio not to try to compile typescript (otherwise it freaks out trying to compile all of angular).  Edit ElephantWeb.csproj, inside `<ProjectGroup>`; add:

   ```
       <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
   ```
6. Also add this section under `<Project>`

   ```
       <ItemGroup>
           <Compile Remove="angular\node_modules\**" />
           <Content Remove="angular\node_modules\**" />
           <EmbeddedResource Remove="angular\node_modules\**" />
           <None Remove="angular\node_modules\**" />
       </ItemGroup>
   ```
7. If you haven't already install NodeJs
8. If you haven't already, install Angular

   `npm install @angular/cli --global`
9. From DOS, go to web project dir

   ```
   mkdir c:\code\Elephant\ElephantSolution\ElephantWeb\angular
   cd c:\code\Elephant\ElephantSolution\ElephantWeb\angular
   ```
10. Copy ag-grid angular sample from https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-angular-seed/tree/master/angular-cli into ...\ElephantWeb\angular
11. Tell angular to compile into Visual Studio "wwwroot" folder instead of "dist".  This makes Visual Studio server angular web pages.  Edit ...\ElephantWeb\angular.angular-cli.json, change

    `"outDir": "dist",`

    to

    `"outDir": "..\wwwroot",`
12. From DOS, do initial compile to force angular to sort out all the dependencies and downloads.

    `npm install`
13. Do some Visual Studio nuget updates to get ready for serving angular from Package Manager console in Visual Studio

    - Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles -version 1.1.2
    - Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc -version 1.1.3
    - Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session -version 1.1.2
14. Tell Visual Studio web project to serve all non-api calls to "index.html".  Change Startup.cs Startup class to this:

    ```
        public class Startup
        {
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddMvc();
            }   
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
                app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    await next();
                    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
                       !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
                       !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
                    {
                        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                        await next();
                    }
                });
                app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                loggerFactory
                    .AddConsole();
            }
        }
    ```
15. Compile angular from DOS, and keep compiling as changes happen

    ```
    cd \code\Elephant\ElephantSolution\ElephantWeb\angular
    ng build --watch
    ```
16. Make sure that it dumps Angular's scaffolding index.html and transpiled *.js into ...\ElephantWeb\wwwroot
17. Run Visual Studio, it should compile C# code, start a browser, and show the ag-grid sample.

Let me know if any of this formatting gets messed up.  Because there are so many files and steps, this really doesn't lend itself to a Plunkr well.  I tried to be explicit in the steps but not get caught up in too much detail.  Let me know if it would be helpful to get more info.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer, you're right I forgot to mention which Framework I am using. I am using the regular .NET Framework because I already have a project in that format. I'm using the .NET Framework with the MVC template so I am using Razer, multiple pages and a small database which I'm trying to display using the ag-grid. Because it is a .NET Framework the whole wwwroot thing won't work I suppose?

Comment: Also I was hoping not to have to compile using the Angular CLI - I tried that and it worked, kind of, but I couldn't compile using VS anymore, had to use 2 consoles (one for dotnet and one for ng serve) and a proxy config file instead ...  The way I have it right now everything seems to be in order and in the right place, my only problem is that VS studio tells me that the ag_grid module can't be found, even though the main.d.ts file is definetly where it's meant to be.

Comment: I aded the TypeScriptCompileBlocked option, the error codes are gone but it simply doesn't run the app...just says "loading"